# Indesign find text not in whole document

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign, grep-indesign

I'm searching for a way to find the text of a specific paragraph style in an InDesign document but without searching the whole document, instead, I want to search only inside a text frame or other object.

The only way I found for now is using `document.findText()` and setting the `findTextPreferences`, is there something like `myTextFrame.findText()`?

Comment: You answered your question, it is myTextFrame.findText();

Comment: But i don't want to search in the whole document, but only inside a specific text frame

Comment: That's exactly what it does. findText() and changeText()  and their GREP variations are working on the parent object. If you use it as a method on the textFrame it will search the text in the frame only. As far as I remember it will ignore the ovorflow text

Comment: Findtext should work on story objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `app.selection[0].findTEXT()`

`app.selection` is an array that contains what you are selecting in Indesign.

And the `[0]` is the first item of the array.

So, you can select the textFrame and do your search.

Or

```
myTextFrame = app.selection[0];
myTextFrame.findText();
```

also works.

This only works on single text frame.
If you want to search in more than 1 textFrame,
you may need to write a for loop to do it.